# why specular light is not running?

Tags: opengl, lighting

this is my method for lighting:

```
private void lights(GL gl) {
    float[] LightPos = {0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f};
    float[] LightAmb = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
    float[] LightDif = {0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f};
    float[] LightSpc = {0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 1.0f};

    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_POSITION, LightPos, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_AMBIENT, LightAmb, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, LightDif, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_SPECULAR, LightSpc, 0);

    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_SPECULAR, LightSpc, 0);

    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHT0);
    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHT1);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHTING);  
}
```

and i see my objects flat, no specular light.. any ideas?

ps. to render my objects:

```
gl.glColor3f(1f,0f,0f);
gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
for(Triangle t : tubeModel.getTriangles()) {
    gl.glVertex3f(t.v1.x, t.v1.y, t.v1.z);
    gl.glVertex3f(t.v2.x, t.v2.y, t.v2.z);
    gl.glVertex3f(t.v3.x, t.v3.y, t.v3.z);
}
gl.glEnd();
```

this is what i'm looking for:[image]

this is what i get:[image]

well it's not all black but if i rotate it becomes grey-white

Comment: how do you set up material? Add it to your post please.

Comment: sorry i'm not able to log-in with that account and with few post i can't comment.
i don't use material..

Comment: I merged your two accounts you should be able to edit it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up material.
Enable material:

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```

Set ambient and diffuse to read from what you set in glColor:

```
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
```

Setup specular. For complete specular you have to have defined specular reflective color and shinines.

```
float specReflection[] = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f };
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, specReflection)
glMateriali(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 56);
```

Shinines is between 1 - 128. Bigger value = more bright.

You can find more help on these links:
http://www.falloutsoftware.com/tutorials/gl/gl8.htm
http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/glsl_lighting_phong.php

Comment: did this answer help?

Comment: houch. thanks to your answer i understand that is not specular light that does not work but diffuse!

Comment: i added some screenshot to explain better!

Comment: Do you specify normal?

Comment: Do you have enabled depth buffer and correctly set up gl_cullface? I will post some code to help you, after i return from work (yeah workoholics works at sunday too :))

Comment: ehm.. yeah.. the normals : )

Comment: Heh ... so problem solved? :)

Answer (score 2):

Agree with [notabene's](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/3794/notabene) answer, material needs to be specified.

But for correct lighting (diffuse and specular) you will also need to specify a normals for each vertex. Although the default normal may create (incorrect) specular reflections.

```
glNormal3f(x,y,z);
```

Comment: This is solved in comments under mine answer. But of course you are right ;)